# How to write i=i*2 condition in for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Here is a for loop in C. How do I represent the `i=i*2` condition in MATLAB?

```
for(i=2; i<n; i=i*2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this vector:

```
powers = 1:(ceil(log2(n))-1);
range = 2.^powers
for idx = range
      % statements
end
```

Comment: This one is `<= n`. Use `ceil(log2(n))-1` instead.

Comment: @user202729 suppose `n=2^k`. Now, `ceil(log2(n))-1` would be `k-1`, not `k`.

Comment: But the question asks for `i < n`.

Comment: @user202729 it's just updated, and I've missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i=2:i.*2:n
  %your code here
end
```